# How to retain the last existing text on the input field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Good day everyone, my instructor gave me an assignment on checkboxes and input fields, he wants the input field to be disabled on default, and open the field once the corresponding checkbox is checked and store the value on that field, and if I un-check the box again, the field should be clear and if I check the same box again, the last input value on the field should show again. I am able to succeed but I found a bug I can't solve, if I check an empty box, my previous stored value from the field becomes `null` again. I already put my variable in global scope but still the variable becomes `null`. (sorry for my english).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="check1" onclick="send()">
    <input type="text"  id="input1" disabled><br>

    <input type="checkbox"  id="check2" onclick="send()">
    <input type="text"  id="input2" disabled><br>

    <script>
        var val1 = null;
        var val2 = null;

        function send() {
            var check1 = document.getElementById('check1').checked;
            var check2 = document.getElementById('check2').checked;

            var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
            var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

            if(check1) {
                input1.disabled = false;
                input1.value = val1;
            } else {
                input1.disabled = true;
                val1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
                input1.value = null;
            }

            if(check2) {
                input2.disabled = false;
                input2.value = val2;
            } else {
                val2 = document.getElementById('input2').value
                input2.disabled = true;
                input2.value = null;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me, inputs remain disabled after I click the checkbox.

Comment: Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/WZKOGR) where your code is working just fine.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi sir try to play on it. try to put text on both field. and uncheck them both . you will see one way or another. the last known inputted text will be gone

Comment: I see the problem now, I am writing a response in a few moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you are handling boths checkboxes together, you need to seperate the processing so that all your checkbox/input combinations are independant from one another.

I altered the `send` function to take parameters and update the corresponding nodes accordingly and updated your HTML to fit.

```js
// create data in which values have keys as the IDs of the inputs
var data = {
    input1: null,
    input2: null
};

function send(checkboxId, inputId) {
    // get checkbox and input
    let checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
    let input = document.getElementById(inputId);

    // handle checkbox and input state
    input.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        input.value = data[inputId];
    }
    else {
        data[inputId] = input.value;
        input.value = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="check1" onclick="send('check1', 'input1')">
<input type="text"  id="input1" disabled><br>

<input type="checkbox"  id="check2" onclick="send('check2', 'input2')">
<input type="text"  id="input2" disabled><br>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much. this works,! easy to understand. though, I am new to object in JS, i wonder how come the var data get connection to the input in HTML? is it because they simply have the same name which is input1 and input2?

Comment: The key names in `data` being the input IDs is simply a choice to simplify accessing the values for each input, because it let me simply do `data[inputId]` to get the value of the input that has that ID. So just a simplification here. I hope I explained that clearly, also if you chose this answer as the correct one, please don't forget to give it a thumbs up.

Comment: yes sir it is clear now! thank you again. and also as of the moment. i cant cast any upvote. since i only got less than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="sending(this.checked, 1)">
  <input type="text" id="input1" disabled onblur="store(this.value, 1)"><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="sending(this.checked, 2)">
  <input type="text" id="input2" disabled onblur="store(this.value, 2)"><br>

  <script>
    var val1 = null;
    var val2 = null;

    function sending(isChecked, which) {
      var check = which === 1 ? 'input1' : 'input2';
      var field = document.getElementById(check);
      if (!isChecked) {
        field.value = null;
      } else {
        field.value = which === 1 ? val1 : val2;
      }
      field.disabled = !isChecked;
    }

    function store(val, which) {
      if (which === 1) {
        val1 = val;
      } else {
        val2 = val;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```